# svn only show changed directorie(project) name

Tags: svn

we have some projects in svn, `a`, `b`, `c` and so on.

when we changes something, we want to only deploy changed project(s) to tomcat, e.g. if we changed `a` and `b`, then just deploy them, we don't want to deploy those unchanged projects.

therefore, i need to find out which projects are changed rather than all files changed, because if there are many files changed, it's hard to figure out which projects are modified by our eyes from logs, sometimes maybe miss one changed project to be deployed to server.

i tried to run `svn status -u`, it will print all files changed, for example:

```
a\src\main\webapp\index.jsp
a\src\main\webapp\a1.jsp
a\src\main\webapp\a2.jsp
b\src\main\webapp\index.jsp
b\src\main\webapp\b1.jsp
b\src\main\webapp\b2.jsp
....
```

but i just want to print :

```
a
b
```

how to achieve that?

i tried use `svn status -u --depth empty` or `svn status -u --depth files`, they just print the latest version number, no changed projects name or changed files name.

Comment: I would try something like [`grep` and `sort`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276741) using regular expression (regex) to search text between start of the line and backslash (`^[^\\]+`).

Comment: @Dialecticus do u mean export all changed files name with their path to a file, then use `grep and sort` command with regex to show the projects name from this file?

Comment: Yes. Also, export to file is not required. You can pipe commands, without having to use a file.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you correctly but maybe `hooks`? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks

Comment: @Dialecticus so in different OS, i need to write different statements, since `grep` is Linux grammar, windows doesn't has it.

Comment: For Windows `findstr` stands for `grep`. Not exactly the same, but it should suffice. Research it a bit. PowerShell is another alternative, it has lots of commands, more powerful than plain command prompt.